# Spring Integration - SFTP FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter is not creating a metadata store file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have the following `InboundChannelAdapter` configured:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "inbound", poller = [Poller(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")])
fun sftpHualingMessageSource(): MessageSource<File> {
    val metadataStore = PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore()
    metadataStore.setBaseDirectory(metadataStoreDirectory)

    val source = SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundHualingFileSynchronizer())
    source.setLocalDirectory(File(sftpLocalDirectoryHualingDownload))
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
    source.setLocalFilter(FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "devices"))

    return source
}
```

However, the `metadata-store.properties` file is not getting created.

I am also seeing weird behavior which I believe is related. When the spring-boot server is restarted, it will process the local copies of the files (csv) again. Then it will try and move the file on the remote server (which is has done already), but when that fails, it will delete it from the folder that it was moved too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I needed to configure the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer` to use the same metadata store that the `InboundChannelAdapter` was using as well.

```
fileSynchronizer.setFilter(SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "devices"))
```

I create the following bean to be `autowired` where needed.

```
@Bean
fun metaDataStore(): PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore {
    val metadataStore = PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore()
    metadataStore.setBaseDirectory(metadataStoreDirectory)
    return metadataStore
}
```

Everything is working as expected and the other issues with files getting deleted are not happening anymore. Also local files are not getting processed again.